# Issues with converting swift 2.3 to swift 3

Tags: swift2, swift3

here is the code which changes image pixels from one to another color

```
 class func processPixelsInImage(inputImage: UIImage,defaultColor:RGBA32,filledColor:RGBA32,currentValue:CGFloat,maxValue:CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        guard let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo) else {
            print("unable to create context")
            return nil
        }

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), inputCGImage)

        let pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))

        var currentPixel = pixelBuffer
        let prevPixel = pixelBuffer

        for i in 0 ..< Int(CGFloat(width)/maxValue*currentValue) {
            for j in 0 ..< Int(height) {
                if currentPixel.memory.color != 0 {
                    if currentValue == maxValue {
                        currentPixel.memory = defaultColor
                    }else {
                        currentPixel.memory = filledColor
                    }
                }
                currentPixel = prevPixel
                currentPixel += (i+width*j)
            }

        }

        let outputCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
        let outputImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage!, scale: inputImage.scale, orientation: inputImage.imageOrientation)
        return outputImage
    }

}
```

When I am trying to convert it to swift 3

```
let pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))
```

on this line I have to change UnsafeMutablePointer to be

```
let pixelBuffer = UnsafeRawPointer(context.data)
```

and because of that in currentPixel object memory property is not found
how can I get pixel memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memory` property has been replaced with the `pointee` property.

Source: https://swift.org/migration-guide/